# Angular5 scroll to a particular element

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have menu and in that I have 4 items, say, 1,2,3,4.

I want to redirect user to same page on click of item 1 and 2 but user should see different portion of the page(scroll down to the page) and this page is also the landing page of the application, so when user logged in then s/he should be top of the page, that is at that time they should not scroll to particular sections for 1 or 2.

When user click on item 1, user should be scrolled down to a section and if click on 3, s/he should redirect to another page(I can manage).

I am using angular material wioth angular5.

Can you help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive for this, like so:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appScroll]'
})
export class ScrollDirective {

  @Input() target;

  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('click') onClick() {
    this.target.scrollIntoView();
  }

}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
<h1 appScroll [target]="head">Hello {{name}}!</h1>
<h2 #head>Test<h2>
```

This takes an element as an input (in the above example, we're passing the h2), and listens for a `click` event (in this case on the h1). If it is clicked, it scrolls the input element into view.

Here is a StackBlitz example. If you click on the "Hello" header, it should scroll the "test" header into view.

https://angular-r9outm.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I tried this but I am getting target alway undefined, so it doesn't work for me. If I pass any string then I am getting it on directive side.

Comment: @Nirmal You need to include `[target]="head"` on the `appScroll` element, where `head` is the reference to the element you want to scroll to. Then you need to include `#head` on that element

Comment: Yes I did the same, but the issue is my header and the element to which I want scroll to, are in separate component, so reference of element is not passed.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was not aware of that.

Comment: let ele2 = document.getElementById('Id');
ele2.scrollIntoView(); I used this and it worked for me